# How to create Google Photos album with specific contributors?

Tags: google-photos

I'd like to create an album on Google Photos, where anyone can comment on pictures, but only specific collaborators can add photos. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible under the current state of development of the app, since the "Collaborate" setting is global.

If you really needed to, you could share the password to the Google account, with your collaborators ([creating a shared 2FA key would make this system smoother](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/125945/109353)).